# Django 2.1.7 - Retrieve all Model fields from user(x)

Tags: python, django

Hello this is my first post on here. I am new to `python` and `django` and I am trying to learn more about both so I am working with them to gain more experience.

I am trying to get all the `metros` for `user(x)` lets say `1`. I want to be able to have `user 1` as the `id` and get all the `metros` associated with that `user`.

**Models**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.
class Metro(models.Model):
class Meta():
    verbose_name_plural = "MetroCards"

    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="Creator")
    metro_name = models.CharField( max_length=30)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.metro_name} by: {self.owner}"
```

**Views**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, Http404
from .models import User, Metro
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
def user(request, user_id):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        metro = Metro.owner.get(pk=user_id)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("User Does Not Exist")
    context = {
        "user": user,
        "metro": metro
    }
    return render(request, "metrocard/user.html", context)
```

**Urls**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    path("user/<str:user_id>", views.user, name="userid"),
    path('map/', views.map, name='map'),
]
```

Html

```
<h1>User Id: {{ user.id}} </h1>
<ul>
    <li>Username: {{ user.username }} </li>
    <li>Email: {{ user.email }} </li>
    {% for met in metro %}
        <li>Metro Name: {{ met.metro_name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}

</ul>
```

Error that I am getting is:

```
'ForwardManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Edit with console traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/bryant/Desktop/metro/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/home/bryant/Desktop/metro/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/home/bryant/Desktop/metro/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/bryant/Desktop/metro/vMetro/metrocard/views.py", line 16, in user
metro = Metro.owner.get(pk=user_id)
AttributeError: 'ForwardManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Could you give us the full log of the error?

Comment: @faruk13 do you want the traceback on the web or the log from the console ?

Comment: from the console would suffice.

Comment: @faruk13 Console traceback inside of the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your view you should change:

```
    metro = Metro.owner.get(pk=user_id)
```

to

```
    metro = user.metro_set.all()
```

Comment: Error: AttributeError at /user/1

'User' object has no attribute 'metro_set'

Comment: @Bryant Try `user.Creator.all()` as you specified the `related_name` for the FK. In the future please do not use capitalized names as `related_name`.

Comment: @awesoon this works. i got it to list all metros. Thanks i had tried user.metro.all() and it didnt work so i didnt think of this.

Answer (score 0):

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model): 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.TextField()
```

views.py

```
def dynamic_lookup_view(request,my_id):
    object = Product.objects.get(id=my_id)
    context = {
        'product':object
    }
    return render(request,'products/product_detail.html',context)
```

urls.py

```
path('products/<int:my_id>/',dynamic_lookup_view)
```

HTML

```
{{ product.title }}
{{ product.description }}
```